# Logical consequence relation

Tags: logic

How to check whether formulas have logical consequence relation or not ?

Consider the problems:

$\forall xA\&\forall xB \ |= \forall x(A\&B) $

$\forall x P\&E \exists Q\&R \ |= P\&Q\&R$

$\forall x(P \implies Q \lor R) \ |= \forall xP \implies Q \lor R$

Where $|=$ logical consequence relation.

I can solve this problem without quantifiers using the implication instead of $|=$ and trying to find out counterexample, but with quantifiers I don't know what is the algorithm to solve this kind of problems ?

Comment: I assume that when it says $\forall x A$ it is assumed that $A$ may have $x$ as a free variable?  As such, can we write this as $\forall x A(x)$?

Comment: @Bram28 yes, I forgot to write it

Comment: No problem!  Now, do you have any thoughts about these?  The first one should be fairly easy ...   Oh, and the second one has something weird going on; please check the formula

Comment: @Bram28 for second seems like in my text book they forgot to add some brackets, therefore I don't exactly know what is the right form of it

Comment: OK, but what's the $E\exists Q$ part? That seems like a typo ... should that just be $\exists Q$?  And the right hand side has no quantifiers at all?

Comment: The third isn't any clearer.  Either you have miscopied, or your textbook is printed in Gibberish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, there is no algorithm that can check for consequence that works for any problem like this.

However, there are several methods and algorithms that *often* do work.

Maybe the easiest thing to do is to try and generate a counterexample: think of a domain of objects, and provide interpretations for the predicates involved so that the left hand side is true, but the right hand side is not ... if you can find such a counterexample: great; you got your answer; the statement on the right is not a consequence of the one on the left.  If you can't find a counterexample ... try a little harder ... and if you still can't find one ... well, maybe it is time to see if you can derive the right side from the left side using rules of equivalence or inference. ... Are you provided with any such rules?

A very nice method that is able to figure out consequence as well as non-consequence is the tree or tableaux method ... but this will take a bit of explanation (if you're interested, just search for it online) .. and I am not sure that that is what your instructor is looking for anyway ...